# Long time uploading video on FireBase using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, video-processing

I am creating an app like TikTok, and I have created the upload option, but it's taking a lot of time to upload the video, approximately 3-4 minutes. How can reduce this time, like it's done on Instagram or YouTube.

This is my code:

```
compressVideoFile(String videoFilePath) async
{
     final compressedVideoFile = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(videoFilePath, quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality);
     return compressedVideoFile!.file;
}

uploadCompressedVideoFileToFirebaseStorage(String videoID, String videoFilePath) async{
  UploadTask videoUploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
      .child("All Videos")
      .child(videoID)
      .putFile(await compressVideoFile(videoFilePath));

   TaskSnapshot snapshot = await videoUploadTask;
   String downloadUrlOfUploadedVideo = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

   return downloadUrlOfUploadedVideo;
}
```

I tried by changing the VideoQuality.LowQuality to  VideoQuality.DefaultQuality or  VideoQuality.MediumQuality, but this did not help me.